# How to Regex this in VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to parse a data from a request to add the links result into a listbox. Here is the html code which I'm trying split.

```
<div class="rc" data-hveid="411"><h3 class="r"><a href="http://google.com/" onmousedown="return rwt
<div class="rc" data-hveid="48"><h3 class="r"><a href="http://google2.com/" onmousedown="return rwt
```

Is just an example. They are a lot...

Here is my code. It works, but not correct.

```
Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.google.ro/search?q=Google")
    Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse
    Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    Dim rssourcecode As String = sr.ReadToEnd
    Dim pp As String = rssourcecode
    Dim strRegex As String = "><a href="".*"""
    Dim myRegex As New Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None)
    For Each myMatch As Match In myRegex.Matches(pp)
        If myMatch.Success Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(myMatch.Value.Split("""").GetValue(1))
        End If
    Next
```

This is the output: http://prntscr.com/9u000g/direct

Help me, please! I just want to get the first 5-6 websites links which Google show at first page.

Example: https://www.google.com/search?q=Google

Output: 
1. https://www.google.com/

2. https://www.facebook.com/Google/
3. https://www.youtube.com/user/Google
4. https://twitter.com/google
5. https://google.com/about/careers/

Comment: It would help if you add in your question what exactly are you trying to parse! You show your code, the data that you want to parse BUT not what you want from it.

Comment: The links from Google Search Results. - https://www.google.com/search?q=Google

Comment: The href value in the search results is a tracking url within google.com which later redirects you to the actual page. You want to look for the green text in the results which actually contains the link.

Comment: Why not use an HTML parser (e.g. [HTML Agility](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack))? Also, have a look [at this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4302070)

Comment: I hate HTML Agility Pack. I prefer Regex. I don't know RegEx at all, but I prefer it over almost anything. Anyway, Youssef Victor solved my problem with a short regex code. Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood you want to get any link exists in the variable **rssourcecode** which means any thing between (href=") and (")

Try using the following code:

```
Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.google.ro/search?q=Google")
Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse
Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
Dim rssourcecode As String = sr.ReadToEnd

Dim MC As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(rssourcecode, "href=""(.*?)""")
For i = 0 To MC.Count - 1
    MsgBox(MC(i).Groups(1).Value)
Next
```

**Edit:**
You can use this pattern to get anything between (/url?q=) and (&amp)

> /url\?q=(.*?)&amp

There is a \ mark between the ? because "?" is a special regex symbol you can escape special symbols by putting \ before it

Comment: It doesn't work. I need only the links between "/url?q=" and "&amp"

Comment: This will be what I need. But it doesn't work... (rssourcecode, "/url?q=(.*?)&amp")

Comment: The previous code gets any thing between href=" and "
Do you want to change it to get anything between /url?q= and &amp ?